# DataTable losing its values when applying filter

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a cached DataTable. I am creating a new DataTable from it and applying filter to it. But when again I acccess the Cached DataTable the rows are getting reduced as per filter. Why is it so?

```
var cachedDataTable = GetDataTableFromCache();
var newDataTable = cachedDataTable;
var filteredRows = cachedDataTable.Select("[Status Type]='test'");
newDataTable  = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we see the code for GetDataTableFromCache() ? I tried duplicating your code but it seems to be working fine on my end. Meanwhile you can try to run a foreach loop and import rows one at a time instead of using CopyToDataTable().

```
            var newDataTable = cachedDataTable.Clone();
            var filteredRows = cachedDataTable.Select("[Status Type]='test'");
            foreach (DataRow row in filteredRows)
            {
                newDataTable.ImportRow(row);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the cachedDataTable is being overwritten when you perform the Select. Performing the Select on the newDataTable may produce different results.

Comment: Yes, But am assigning the cacheddatatable to new datatable